# Https is showing content of some other domains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, https, whm

I have single Ip address and 20 domains under it.And one ssl is installed to that ip address.Whenever any of the 20 domains is accessed with https , Its showing some other site where ssl is installed.

My question is how to disable that and just show the same sites content.google is indexing my https and now all of my 20 domains homepage is same in google.

Answer (score 0):

And if you redirect other domains to http ?

You can use in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !domainwithssl\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```